# mvinnstr returns an empty string with ncurses instead of the line

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses, curses

I am working on a basic text editor in ncurses and I can't get mvinnstr to work and return the current line of text that the user is on as a string.

```c
void updateline(size_t n) { // updates selected line of text (n)
        int tmp_len = linelen(n); // linelen returns length of the line
        char *s = malloc(tmp_len+1);
        long int i = mvinnstr(n,0,s,tmp_len);
        printw("%s%i", s,i);
        free(s);
}
```

For some reason i is always equal to 18, and s remains empty when I run it whereas I thought it should return i as the amount of chars read in and s should be the chars themselves!
I've been stuck on this reading documentatio and I can't see what is wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This comment "s remains empty" is ambiguous, and since your sample code is incomplete, no one can do anything with it.

Comment: Have you checked that `linelen()` (which we can't see) is returning correct values?

Comment: regarding: `long int i = mvinnstr(n,0,s,tmp_len);`   The function: `mvinnstr()` returns a `int`, not a `long int`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `char *s = malloc(tmp_len+1);`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding:   `printw("%s%i", s,i);`  where are you expecting the cursor to be after the call to `mvinnstr()`?   `6.3. printw() class of functions. mvprintw() can be used to move the cursor to a position and then print. If you want to move the cursor first and then print using printw() function,